# C++ command line argument comparison

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I am doing some validation of the arguments passed by command line in C++ and am having some difficulties.

I am doing like so

```
./a.exe inputfile.txt outputfile.txt 16 flush_left
```

And I am trying to do the validation like so

```
if(argv[4] == "flush_left" || argv[4] == "flush_justify" || argv[4] == "flush_right"){
```

And its not working out as planned. Though I am not seeing why this won't work. From everything I've read and seen that should be just fine

Comment: @moi No. `0: ./a.exe`, `1: inputfile.txt`, `2: outputfile.txt`, `3: 16`, `4: flush_left`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try:

```
std::string argv4 = argv[4];
if(argv4 == "flush_left" || argv4 == "flush_justify" || argv4 == "flush_right"){
  //...
}
```

or (untested):

```
if( argc >=4 && (!strcmp(argv[4],"flush_left")  || !strcmp(argv[4],"flush_justify") || !strcmp(argv[4],"flush_right")) ) {
  //...
}
```

argv[4] has type `char*`, and string literals have type `const char*`, you cant compare the content of those types (=text) using the `==` operator, you would have to use something like `strcmp` or the `std::string` class instead.

Using `==` on `char*` compares the address of the variables, not the content.

Comment: Another possibility is to use strcmp(). I'd go with std::string, as you have shown, however.

Comment: "strcmp/strncmp returns the amount of characters which don't match" - that's a brave assertion. Care to state your source for that?

Comment: @pax Brave is one word for it :)

Comment: Oh, well, smerlin won't fix the error, I guess we'll have to do it ourselves :-)

Comment: I think `strncmp()` is inappropriate - use `strcmp()`.  If you use `strncmp()`, then the argument `flush_leftwards` would be treated as equal to `flush_left`.  If you do use `strncmp()`, use (for example): `strncmp(argv[4], "flush_left", sizeof("flush_left"))` (equivalent to 11 for the third argument) as it checks that the last character is a '`\0`'.

Comment: Good point, @Jonathon. Since both `argv[n]` (where 0 < `n` < `argc`) and `"xyz"` will always be null-terminated, it's a waste using `strncmp`.

Comment: yes, using `strcmp` is ok, but you will have to add a check for `argc>=4` then, or shit happens, i will edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @paxdiablo: hmm, i stand corrected. I never used strcmp for anything else besides checking if 2 strings are equal, so my memories about the excact api of strcmp were hmm ...corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

./a.exe inputfile.txt outputfile.txt 16 flush_left

A zero based argv gives you:
argv[0] = a.exe
argv[1] = inputfile.txt
argv[2] = outputfile.txt
argv[3] = 16
argv[4] = flush_left

so the index is correct, however you should use strcmp(stringa, stringb) and make sure that returns 0 instead.